# Calculate the row-wise weighted sum for a set of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have, say, the following data frame:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> dd <- tibble(a = rep(1,10), b = rep(1,10), c = rep(1,10))
> dd
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       a     b     c
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1
 3     1     1     1
 4     1     1     1
 5     1     1     1
 6     1     1     1
 7     1     1     1
 8     1     1     1
 9     1     1     1
10     1     1     1
```

and a vector of weights:

```
> weight <- c(1, 5, 10)
> weight
[1]  1  5 10
```

when I want to calculate the row-wise weighted sum for all the columns of the dataframe together, I do this:

```
> dd %>% mutate(m = rowSums(map2_dfc(dd, weight,`*`)))
# A tibble: 10 × 4
       a     b     c     m
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1    16
 2     1     1     1    16
 3     1     1     1    16
 4     1     1     1    16
 5     1     1     1    16
 6     1     1     1    16
 7     1     1     1    16
 8     1     1     1    16
 9     1     1     1    16
10     1     1     1    16
```

but I don't know how to calculate the row-wise weighted sum for a **subset** of the data frame. I tried the code below, but it gives messy results:

```
> dd %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(m = rowwise(map2_dfc(c_across(b:c), weight[2:3],`*`)))
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Rowwise: 
       a     b     c m$...1 $...2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1      5    10
 2     1     1     1      5    10
 3     1     1     1      5    10
 4     1     1     1      5    10
 5     1     1     1      5    10
 6     1     1     1      5    10
 7     1     1     1      5    10
 8     1     1     1      5    10
 9     1     1     1      5    10
10     1     1     1      5    10
```

Can someone please give me a hint as to how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` methods, we can create a named vector for 'weight', loop `across` the columns 'b' to 'c', subset the 'weight' value based on the column name (`cur_column()`), multiply and get the `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
names(weight) <- names(dd)
dd %>% 
   mutate(m = rowSums(across(b:c,  ~ .x * weight[cur_column()])))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
       a     b     c     m
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1    15
 2     1     1     1    15
 3     1     1     1    15
 4     1     1     1    15
 5     1     1     1    15
 6     1     1     1    15
 7     1     1     1    15
 8     1     1     1    15
 9     1     1     1    15
10     1     1     1    15
```

---

Or if we want to use `rowwise` (not recommended as it is slower)

```
dd %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(m = sum(c_across(b:c) * weight[2:3])) %>%
  ungroup
```

---

Or use `crossprod`

```
dd %>%
   mutate(m = crossprod(t(pick(b:c)), weight[2:3])[,1])
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
dd$m <-  rowSums(dd[2:3] * weight[2:3][col(dd[2:3])])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is matrix multiplication. Your original is equivalent to `as.matrix(dd) %*% weight`. For a subset inside `mutate` you can do this:

```
dd %>% mutate(m = (across(b:c) %>% as.matrix()) %*% weight[1:2])
```